Access denied trying to execute c# console application
First up, I'll admit I'm a total noob at this.  I'm just trying to learn, but it gets hard when I hit this kind of problem.  Google hasn't provided any answers so I thought I'd ask here.
I built my program and it was completely successful, no errors or warnings.  When I do dotnet run, I get this in red:

Unhandled exception: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (5): An error occurred trying to start process (path to the .exe) with working directory (path to the project root).  Access is denied.

I restarted command prompt as Administrator but the problem persists.  I checked permissions for the directory and it has SYSTEM, myself, and Administrators group, all with full control.
So at this point I'm stuck.  What have I done wrong?

Probably there's still a version of the exe running. Find and abort the process in the Task Manager.

This is the first time I ever tried running it.

If the project built correctly and you see the .exe file then you have a problem with the security software that runs on that machine.  Temporarily disable it and try again.
